# What is this record-destroying scene in Family Guy a reference to?

Tags: reference, family-guy

In Family Guy season 7 episode 2, Peter drives the family crazy playing the [Bird is the Word](https://youtu.be/aPrtFxd9u9Y) song.

Later in the episode, Brian and Stewie are shown destroying the record, in a method which seems as though it's a reference to a scene in another film or tv series:

Am I correct that this is a reference? If so, what is it a reference to?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Didn't even have to watch the video--the thumbnail was enough to know that **this parodies the printer-destroying scene in *[Office Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/).***

Comment: Certainly looks like a shot-for-shot match, but I'd say the Office Space scene *also* looks like a reference to something (probably a brutal murder in some other film). I'm thinking they both reference the same source; any ideas? I've seen a couple of mentions on the internet that it's from a murder scene in Casino, but that seems very different.

Comment: I think the Office Space is "inspired" by the scene in Casino where Joe Pesci's character and his brother are taken out into the corn field by fellow gangsters (hence the "Gansta rap" music in O.S.). It's not exactly the same, but the brutality as an expression of anger and "having enough of them" is I think the point of both scenes.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1igvrZ0KosA&has_verified=1

Comment: That I did not know.  Interesting.

Comment: @J.Raefield I know that Casino is quite an old movie (which I haven't seen) but you've put a spoiler in your comment.

Comment: @camden_kid In Meta discussions in the past, the community decided that the only place we normally need concern ourselves with spoilers is the title of the question. Spoiler marks are not needed in the body of the question, any answers, or comments.

Answer (score -3):

Its probably a reference to the Disco Demolition Night https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disco_Demolition_Night

Basically a stunt by a fired rock DJ

Comment: That's what I though too.

Comment: If they were doing a Disco Demolition Night reference, it's more likely they would have parodied the main event and had Stewie and Brian blow the record up with dynamite.